# Error con job para envio de mail con librería win32com python

Tags: python, email

Tengo un job (BlockingScheduler) que envía mail todos los días desde outlook, pero de vez en cuando recibo este error:

```
Job "send_mail (trigger: cron[day_of_week='mon-fri', hour='9', minute='42'], next run at: 2024-02-21 09:42:00 -03)" raised an exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\apscheduler\executors\base.py", line 125, in run_job
    retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documentos\file\send_mail.py", line 579, in send_mail_function
    newmail.Send()
  File "<COMObject CreateItem>", line 2, in Send
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147023170, 'Error en la llamada a procedimiento remoto.', None, None)
```

Este error puede ser resuelto reiniciando el codigo u outlook, pero me gustaría saber por que tengo este error, para no tener que estar pendiente del job y que trabaje automaticamente.

Gracias de antemano :)

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! Traduce tu pregunta, de lo contrario terminará [cerrada](/help/closed-questions).